# Spring Webflux Mono is ignoring ResponseEntity's status and returning 200 OK

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux

I have a RestController which looks like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
class UserController(val userService: UserService) {

  @PostMapping("/register")
  fun register(@RequestBody body: UsernamePasswordResource): Mono<*> {
    return userService.createUser(body.username, body.password)
        .map {ResponseEntity(it, HttpStatus.CREATED)}
        .doOnError {
          if (it is DuplicateUserException){
            ResponseEntity(ErrorResource(it.message!!), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
          } else {
            ResponseEntity(ErrorResource("Internal server error"), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
          }
        }
  }
}
```

When I create a using using this endpoint 200 OK in response and this as body:

```
{
  "headers": {},
  "body": {
    "username": "test7",
    "passwordEncoded": "4HxMMUI09pltEr9pyKIxsQ==",
    "description": ""
  },
  "statusCode": "CREATED",
  "statusCodeValue": 201
}
```

Why is the status of my ResponseEntity ignored and 200 is returned? How do i fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The endpoint was returning `Mono<*>`

After I changed my service to return `AuthenticationResource` instead of `UserResource`
I could also make the endpoint return `Mono<ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResource>>`.

After that the ResponseEntity was respected and used as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides an **HTTP 200 (OK**) response by default when an endpoint returns successfully. To return a custom **HTTP** status, use the **@ReponseStatus** annotation above your function and pass your status code in the parenthesis. Your code snippet should look like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
class UserController(val userService: UserService) {

  @PostMapping("/register")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  fun register(@RequestBody body: UsernamePasswordResource): Mono<*> {
    return userService.createUser(body.username, body.password)
        .map {ResponseEntity(it, HttpStatus.CREATED)}
        .doOnError {
          if (it is DuplicateUserException){
            ResponseEntity(ErrorResource(it.message!!), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
          } else {
            ResponseEntity(ErrorResource("Internal server error"), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
          }
        }
  }
}
```